# Where to keep the resources.xml file for Rundeck CLI

Tags: rundeck

I am using Rundeck CLI. Where should I keep the resource.xml file so that it is available for the given project? Is there any specific location the file needs to be or it can be in any folder and one just point out to the location?

Answer (score 0):

No specific place is needed for the `resources.xml`/`resources.yaml` files (also, you can use any name for that file btw, for example: `project_test.xml`). You can use any location reachable by the `rundeck` user (RPM/DEB-based installations) or reachable by the user that launches Rundeck (WAR-based installation). A good place to store these files could be the `/var/lib/rundeck/` path.

Comment: I tried keeping the resource file under /var/lib/rundeck and /var/rundeck. Still no success. I have installed "rd-cli" using the zipfile. Do I require to add any environment variables other than the added in ~/.rd/rd.conf ?

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to do? I refer to the resource.xml file in a Rundeck Project, Rundeck CLI is a tool to interact with a Rundeck Instance.